# Regex to accept one word and reject another

Tags: regex

I have two strings:

```
"/admin/questions"
"/questions"
```

I need to match the string that has "questions" but not "admin".

For not having "admin" I am using:

```
^(?!.*admin).*$
```

It seems to work ... Is this the simplest option?

And how to add "has questions" rule to it?

Comment: Are those your full strings? If so, you could just match on `/^\/questions/`.

Comment: Could you maybe add 4-5 strings with the desired output for them? As I understood it has to contain `questions` and must not contain `admin`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly your sugestion almost works. But how to macth when the string is only '/'?

Comment: I think for simple case of '/' I must use ^\/$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(?!  )` part is a *negative* look-ahead to see if there is **no** match for `.*admin`. You could use a regular (or *positive*) look-ahead (`(?=  )`) and check for `.*questions` like so:

```
^(?!.*admin)(?=.*questions).*$
```

Comment: or more simply `^(?!.*admin).*questions.*$`